# How to filter rows from a csv file based on threshold numerical values using python

Tags: python, csv, filter

I have a .csv file with three columns and many rows, where the 1st column is names and the 2nd and 3rd columns are values. I want to filter out any rows that have values less than 1. So I wrote a script to read through the file and write to a new file if the values in `row[1] and row[2]` are `>=1`. However, my output file contains everything in my input file, including rows with 0's. I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
from sys import argv

script, filename, outputfile = argv

import csv
#with open(filename,'r'), open (outputfile,'w') as fin, fout:
with open(filename,'r') as fin, open (outputfile,'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')       
    for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=','):
        #if row[1] and row[2] >= 1:
        if row[1] >=1 and row[2] >= 1:
             writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Remember that `"0" > 1` is `True`. Are you sure you read in numbers from the CSV, and not strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string to int:

```
import csv
with open(filename,'r') as fin, open (outputfile,'w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=',')       
    for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=','):
        if int(row[1]) >=1 and int(row[2]) >= 1:
             writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: awesome. thanks!

As a side note, I ended up converting to floats because many of the values contained long decimals.